# IKVM: How to convert PdfBox 2.0.* into .Net set of libraries?

Tags: java, c#, pdfbox, ikvm

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460987/pdfbox-building-the-latest-version-for-net-using-ikvm) question, but a bit newer

I am looking for .Net version of PdfBox 2.0.15. The latest version I am able to find is 1.8.9.

I've tried to convert [jar file with dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.15) by myself, but having an exception:

> The type initializer for 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument' threw an exception.

On the project [site](https://pdfbox.apache.org/building.html), there is a notice about deprecated possibility to build the product using Ant since version 2.

Is it still possible to get IKVM version of PdfBox 2.0.15 for .Net?

Comment: IKVM has been discontinued in 2017.

Comment: Does it mean I am not able to convert PdfBox 2.0.* to .Net version using the latest available version of IKVM?

Comment: I don't know if it would convert or not. I just think it is not a good idea to use a software that has been discontinued.

Comment: I most likely found a bug in IKVM last year: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4312 (just search for "IKVM" in the page, without the quotes).

Comment: i still use ikvm for pdfbox but not 2.0. it is  Pdfbox-IKVM1.8.9. Someone tried to port 2.0 before but i do not know why he removed it afterwards.